# Third-Party Oracle Providers for .Net with object type support

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net

I'm looking for a third-party Oracle Data Provider for .Net (ADO.NET) with a full support of Oracle object types (like geometries). I was foolish enough to use ODP.NET and now I'm paying the price - it's incredibly buggy and I just reached the end of the line (keep crashing IIS Pool - known issue, no resolution). I found dotConnect which is fine, just 4 times slower with object types than ODP.NET. Are any others providers which support Oracle objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware of the Oracle-published ADO.net provider ? this dll ships with the Oracle CLient, and is named Oracle.DataAccess.dll.  The version I am using is ver 1.102.4.0, and is dtd 2/11/2008.

Comment: This will be deprecated in the next version of C#

Comment: Hi Charles,
I've checked this file, still its ODP driver (your is actually from version 10.2.4 - no support for objects). 11g Client supports objects, but it's already given me such a headache - pooling failing, metadata cache broken, and now these problems in IIS - nightmare.

Comment: Microsoft's System.Data.OracleClient will go out of support, not the ODP.Net from Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

As I'm looking into working with Oracle database from C#, here is what I can say as an update to this question.

These are the alternatives:

- Microsoft's **System.data.OracleClient** is part of the .Net framework and requires Oracle Client installed or external dll's (but I think it's not supported anymore)
- **Oracle Data Provider for .Net** (ODP.Net), is the offcial .Net provider from Oracle. I think it is part of Oracle Client install.
- Third party **Devart dotConnect** for Oracle ([follow me](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/)).
- Third party **Datadirect ADO.Net provider** for Oracle ([follow me](http://www.datadirect.com/products/net/net-for-oracle/)).

I didn't dig deeper yet, but information is not so easy to find about Oracle connectors, so here is my contribution ;-)

Comment: -1. Old question and all drivers you listed have already been mentioned in the other answers. (dotConnect in the answer, datadirect by Theo, oracle driver by Charles)

Comment: Old question, yet still relevant, and because StackOverflow is both a Q&A and a knowledge base :
1/ It was worth an update for those who search for Oracle providers now, in 2011 (regarless the list is the same or not, it's good to know);
2/ One summarized answer is better, IMO, than a list of partial answers.
Is that really so bad that it deserves a "-1" ?

Answer (score 0):

There is also this provider: http://www.datadirect.com/products/net/net_for_oracle/index.ssp . I don't know whether it supports spatial type mdsys.sdo_geometry.

Comment: Hi Theo,
No they don't supporty Oracle object types. I've already contacted them and unfortunatelly only "normal" types are supported. I guess I'll choose dotConnect - a performance hit is a small price to pay for quality.

Answer (score 0):

In the last release [Telerik OpenAccess](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx) introduced a flexible type mapping system which allows developers to easily work with custom DB types/UDTs.  It ships with support for Geometric/Geographic data, and it is easy to create your own type converter to tell OpenAccess how to map any custom types you may have. The type converters work for all [DBs OA supports](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm/supported-databases.aspx), one of which is Oracle. :)